# Apache activemq and iscsi

Tags: apache, virtual-machine, activemq-classic, mount, iscsi

We are planning to use the iscsi target to handle the Activemq master/slave setup.  In this case we will mount a SAN storage volume on two virtual machines using the iscsi protocol and those two VMs would share the same mount (from SAN).  So the question is, will the file locking works properly with this approach?  And can we anticipate any issues in this design?

Mounting as NFS may need a fileserver between SAN and the VMs so we are not considering this as an option and planning to use iscsi.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a clustered, "shared disk" filesystem on the iSCSI LUNs.  Conventional filesystems (ext3, xfs, ntfs, etc.) do not expect (or handle) the data changing out from underneath them.  They just won't work.

I don't have any particular one to recommend, but the most accessible of these shared-disk filesystems is probably GFS2?  The wikipedia page for clustered filesystems has several examples listed under the **Shared-disk file system** heading.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system

Comment: Did some research on the GFS2 and it looks to be a good option.  Thanks for the tip!